# Update records using select query with subquery returning error

Tags: sql

Error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I understand this error, but I don't know how to rewrite the query to avoid it.  I'm looking for records with duplicate values in f1, f2, and f3 based on the timestamp of the file they were imported from.  The records not in the subquery should be modified as indicated.  I don't need the import_file_timestamp in my results but I believe I have to include it to select the proper version of the record.  The subquery, by itself, returns the correct information.  How do I do this?

```
update      import_raw_records
set         raw_record_status = 'I'
from        import_raw_records
where       f1+f2+f3 NOT IN (
            select      a.f1+a.f2+a.f3,
                    max(b.import_file_timestamp)
            from        import_raw_records a
            inner join  import_files b
            on      a.import_file_id = b.import_file_id
            group by    a.f1+a.f2+a.f3)
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: What is the database that you are using?

Comment: I have never seen an SQL flavor where `+` meant `AND`. That part seems wrong.